# Android Widget set android:updatePeriodMillis programmatically

Tags: android, widget

I'm working on a widget and I have a default update interval, but I want the user to be able to change that interval, can I modify the updatePeriodMillis from the code? or I have to use the AlarmManager?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can I modify the updatePeriodMillis from the code?

No, sorry.

> or I have to use the AlarmManager?

Yes.