# Android widget's fixed update frequency

Tags: java, android, android-widget

In order to have [Widget](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html), we need to maintain an XML file (AppWidgetProviderInfo) which describes the properties of the widget, e.g. size or fixed update frequency like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="160dp" 
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000"
    android:configure="android.project.WidgetConfigure" >

</appwidget-provider>
```

and Maintain the App Widget configuration in the AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<meta-data
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
 </receiver>
```

I know that we can not edit the `updatePeriodMillis`. programmatically and we need to use AlarmManager. ([Android Widget set android:updatePeriodMillis programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14198924/android-widget-set-androidupdateperiodmillis-programmatically))

But how can I read that value from the xml file programmatically. Is there any way ?

Addenda:

```
try {
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        AppWidgetProviderInfo info = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(R.xml.widget_info);
        System.out.println("Time: " + info.updatePeriodMillis);
    } catch(Exception err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If I use this code in an Activity, it returns NullPointerException in catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`updatePeriodMillis` is a value which the system uses in order to send you a proper broadcast once that period's time has come. 
Why will you want to read it and trigger an `AlarmManager` intent for the exact same time?

**After your edit:**
You are passing the wrong "id"; you should pass the actual widget id, not its XML metadata id.
As I wrote in my last comment, try this:
`AppWidgetManager.getInstance()`, then use `AppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds()` to retrieve your widget(s) id, then continue as discussed (`AppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo()` ...)

Comment: I don't want to do that. That sentence was just an information with the link, but I wanted to see how to read it.

Comment: Oh, I see. There is more then one way to do it, but did you consider simply read the file and parse it?
Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329308/open-xml-file-from-res-xml-in-android

Comment: It means that I have to parse the xml file and there is no simpler code. is it what you meant?

Comment: No, you mustn't read the file itself, you can call `AppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo()`, then read `AppWidgetProviderInfo.updatePeriodMillis`

Comment: It was a good point. But then it seems that I can get it with this code as you said (and I add as Addenda) within the Widget Class (extends AppWidgetProvider). `not in other activities.` but +1 for your guides till now.

Comment: Have you tried the following code from your Activity? `AppWidgetManager.getInstance()`, then use `AppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds()` to retrieve your widget(s) id, then continue as above (`AppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo()` ...)

Comment: Yes, the codes are added at the end of my question, but returns NullPointerException.